# Setting environment variables for a django project

Tags: python, django, pycharm, environment-variables

I am using PyCharm on Windows and want to set the environment variables for Django website. I have tried two approaches:

### **1. activate.bat**

I am setting the values in the project's venv:

[image]

**activate.bat**

```py
@echo off

set "VIRTUAL_ENV=D:\Git\QV-PublicWebsite\venv"
set DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='random'
...
```

**activate.ps1**

```py
...
$VIRTUAL_ENV = $BASE_DIR
$env:VIRTUAL_ENV = $VIRTUAL_ENV
$env:DJANGO_SECRET_KEY='random'
...
```

When I load the project in PyCharm, I can see that the venv is active.
[image]

But when I start debugging the project, I am not able to read the values:
[image]

This is the settings that I have for debugging the project:
[image]

### **2. Env File**

I have also tried using EnvFile tab and import my `.env` file

[image]

This way, when I debug the project in PyCharm, the environment variables are set as expected.

However when I want to build the migrations then the environment variables are not set again!

[image]

Comment: just set them under environment config .,.. . all it does is run it with that interpretter ... it doesnt actually run activate (ie where it says `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: thanks, are you able to give a little more details? How to set them under environment config?

Comment: ... click the list looking thing to the right of `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1`

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Do you mean I need to add the environment variables one by one? I have quite a big list of variables...

Comment: @JoranBeasley: I have tried adding the `.env` file from PyCharm (EnvFile tab)... this way the debugger works, but when I run `python manage.py makemigrations` again the environment variables go missing

Comment: envfile(and other environment vars) only affects if you are running via a play button ...  if you are running in the shell you can just activate your env before hand from inside the terminal ...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a virtual environment for your Django Website the simple way is as follows:-

***->. Create Environment variable by :***
python -m venv <virtual_env_name>

->. After the Virtual environment got created you have 2 approaches to activating it

***i.By using CMD.***
cd <virtual_env_path>\Scripts\activate.bat  **[NOTE : Please make sure to use Backward slash '\']**

***ii. By using Pycharm interpreter***
- go to settings in Pycharm than select interpreter settings and add python interpreter
- in add settings select interpreter and in scripts dir choose **python.exe**
and you are ready to use your virtual environment